# Navigating to an element id using react router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I am trying to use react router to navigate to specific elements on a webpage. 
I have attempted BrowserRouter implementations but can seem the get them to work.

I had the thought that maybe referencing an element by Id was was not working because the call to the element was happening before the element was actually rendered to the DOM. However, even after the page fully loads the Links still do not work.

### Router

```
const history = createHistory();

class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter
        history={history}>
        <div>
          <Menu/>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={HomePage} exact={true} />
            <AdminRoute path="/admin" component={AdminPage} />
            <Route path="/plays" component={PlaysPage} />
            <Route path="/prose" component={ProsePage} />
            <Route path="/events" component={EventsPage} />
            <Route path="/content/:id" component={ContentDisplay} />
            <Route path="/create-account" component={CreateAccountPage} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default AppRouter;

export { history };
```

### Link

```
<Link to="/plays#ten-minute-plays" className="menu__nav menu__nav--hitbox">
    10 Minute Plays
</Link>
```

### Element

```
class PlaysPage extends React.Component{
  state = {
    plays: this.props.content
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.startSetContent()
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({ plays: this.props.content });
        history.push(`/${window.location.pathname}`)
      });
  }

  render () {
    return(
      <div className="plays"> 
        <div className="ten-min-plays">
          <h1 id="ten-minute-plays" className="ten-min-plays__title">
            10 Minute Plays
          </h1>
        <div/>
      <div/>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use pass object parameter instead of string for `to`? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md#to-object